# place nodes (automatically) without overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I generate a bunch of nodes (in python) that differ in size and need to place them so that they do not overlap.
For the example the latex forloop was generated (again: actual data is not latex generated). But the result looks pretty similar to the left example - the nodes overlap.

I guess the most intuitive solution to placing the nodes would be a kind of column orientation where the current node node is placed into the next free "column" if the previous node occupies that place.

At generation time, I do not know the latex generated node's height (however inaccurate assumptions based on content length in chars or newlines are possible - it is vastly more than the '.x' in the example)

Is there a way to give Latex a bunch of nodes and it figures the positions out for itself?
What would be an alternative solution?

mwe:

https://www.latex4technics.com?note=zzvqsh

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{fit} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,0.5,...,3}
\node[inner sep=10pt, draw] at (1,\i) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-2) -- (0,3);
\node[inner sep=10pt, draw] at (1,0) {0};
\node[inner sep=10pt, draw] at (2.1,0.5) {0.5};
\node[inner sep=10pt, draw] at (3.2,1) {1};
\node[inner sep=10pt, draw] at (1,1.5) {1.5};
\node[inner sep=10pt, draw] at (2.1,2) {2};
\node[inner sep=10pt, draw] at (3.2,2.5) {2.5};
\node[inner sep=10pt, draw] at (1,3) {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:
I forgot to mention the important side note:
For my application the node's y-coordinate has to be fix**

Answer (score 4):

For instance, `chains` are designed to create chains of non-overlapping nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,chains} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[start chain=going above,node distance=1ex,
    nodes={inner sep=10pt, draw,minimum width=3.5em,on chain}]
 (1,0) foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,3} {node{$\pgfmathprintnumber\x$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, i forgot to mention (see edit) that the node's y coordinate is fix in my application - that renders the use of chains probably inadequate

Comment: @weltio If *all* y coordinates are fixed, and the nodes have certain sizes, they may just overlap. If you want to fix the y coordinate of one particular node, `chains` are appropriate. In the example you can replace `(1,0)` by any coordinate, which will determine the location of the first node of the chain, and the others will be placed relative to that one according to the rules (such as `going above,node distance=1ex`).

Comment: as in the example above a fixed y coordinate does not have to result in overlapping. one could just move the node on the x axis? I will look into chains; thx